# How do I toggle the jQuery Mobile Accordion with a button click?

Tags: jquery-mobile

When creating a jQuery Mobile Accordion, how do I get a section of the accordion to open when a button is clicked?

When the user clicks the search button, I want to load the results into a list in the second panel, collapse the first and expand the second.

```
<div data-role="collapsible-set">

    <div id="filterContainer" data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false">
        <h3>Filters</h3>
        <p>controls to pick options</p>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="search">Search</a>
    </div>

    <div id="resultsContainer" data-role="collapsible">
        <h3>Results</h3>
        <p>list of results</p>
    </div>

<div>
```

Comment: I guess I found an answer, but not sure if it's the "right" one:  `$('#resultsContainer a:first').click();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Live Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/h2pPz/19/

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home" class="type-home"> 
    <div data-role="content">
        <div data-role="collapsible-set">

            <div id="filterContainer" data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false">
                <h3>Filters</h3>
                <p>controls to pick options</p>
                <!-- Either button syntax works -->
                <!-- <a href="#" data-role="button" id="search">Search</a> -->
                <input type="button" value="Search" id="search"/>
            </div>

            <div id="resultsContainer" data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
                <h3>Results</h3>
                <p>list of results</p>
            </div>

        <div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#search').click(function() {
    $('#resultsContainer').trigger('expand');
});
```

Comment: Where is this in the documentation?

Comment: hmm I saw it on the forums somewhere: trigger('expand') and .trigger('collapse')